# Getting each i element of a ruby array in a javascript function (escaping and unescaping)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Say, in ruby I've got an array: `ruby_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

In my javascript script, I want to be able to push every element from my`ruby_array` to a `javascriptArray`:

```
var javascriptArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < <%= raw ruby_array.size %>; i++) {
   alert("The " + i + ". element of my ruby array is: " + <%= raw ruby_array[i] %>);
   // Problem: I guess, I cannot get the i javascript variable when calling ruby_array[i]
   // How do I unescape the i?

   // Now push every ruby_array element into my javascriptArray
   // Same problem like above
   javascriptArray[i] = Number(<%= raw ruby_array[i] %>);
}
```

The error message I get is:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

Note: If I leave the [i] in `ruby_array[i]` out, the output is fine:

> The 0. element of my ruby array is: 1,2,3,4,5
>
> ...
>
> The 4. element of my ruby array is: 1,2,3,4,5

I've also tried `.to_json.html_safe` with the same results. So how do I get the i-th element from my ruby array in javascript code?

Comment: your javascript variable `i` will not be known in `<%= raw ruby_array[i] %>`

Comment: ah ... as stated in your comments

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the problem. So how can I unescape the i and tell ruby that the i from my javascript loop is meant :)?

Comment: You can't interop javascript and ruby in that way, you'll need to transform your ruby data to a plain javascript array and then access it through: `jsArray[i];`.

Comment: @praszyk: Oh, good to know. One question: When I convert my ruby array into a javascript array, are the elements in my javascript array also numbers? Or do I have to convert them as well into numbers?

Comment: They are numbers, sorry for answering so late. Also booleans are booleans. I think there is an exception for Dates because you can't effectively store Date Objects in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these will escape js.

You can try:

```
var javascriptArray = <%= escape_javascript ruby_array.to_json %>
```

or

```
var javascriptArray = <%= j ruby_array.to_json %>
```

Comment: Oh my, that seems a lot easier, than creating a loop and push every ruby item into the new javascriptArray. Thanks! One question: Since I need my elements as numbers, will the new javascriptArray contain numbers as well or are they strings?

Answer (score 0):

i have not tested it but this should work

```
var javascriptArray = [<%= j(ruby_array.join(',')) %>];
```

Comment: No, that way you'll get syntax errors if any value in the ruby array is a string. You need to use escape_javascript...